# Converting char array into hex adress

Tags: arrays, char, hex

I am writing software for my STM32 µC in order to read data from the flash when receiving a certain address value from my Computer program via UART.  The Computer Programm sends me a value bytewise (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 --> address I want to read data from), and I am reading it into a char array (char address = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]). That works so far. In order to read data from the received address value, I need to convert this char Array into a hex address (i.e. int hexaddress =  0x12345678). Does somebody know how to do that with a Footprint as small as possible?

Please have mercy with me, I am an electrical engineer and a girl on top haha…

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking for this in the C programming language, and therefore this problem is trivial. The following code should work, and requires minimal libraries (`stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`). I also assume that the hex `char` array will always have 8 digits, and therefore be a 64-bit number.

```
int hex_str_to_int(char hexdata[8])
{
    int ret = 0x00;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // assuming your hexdata will always be a string of 8 hex chars
        if (hexdata[7-i] >= 'A') ret += ((hexdata[7-i] - 55) << (4*i));
        else if (hexdata[7-i] >= '0') ret += ((hexdata[7-i] - 48) << (4*i));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The code above loops through your `char hexdata[8]` array and if the alphanumeric character at the index (inverse) is a number > `'A'` then it will subtract `55`, making `'A'` equal to 10, and `'F'` equal to 15. It then shifts this value right `4*I` bits, and adds it to the return value. A similar thing occurs when the character is between 0-9, however the subtraction constant is `48` to position the value between 0 and 9.

The following function can be applied as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char hex_data[8] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};
    printf("0x%08x\n", hex_str_to_int(hex_data));
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
0x12345678
```